# How to add one another library files with different name from the theme name?

Tags: 8, theming

I try to define a separate library with different name from the theme name, according to this artcle:
[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)
For example a library with below details:

- **Theme name:** MyThemeName
- **Library Name:** Library A
- **Library File Name:** libfile.info.yml

**libfile.libraries.yml**

```
LibraryA:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/Style.css: {}
```

And then attach this library to all page in:

**MyThemeName.info.yml**

```
libraries:
  - MyThemeName/LibraryA
```

I would be happy to hear what the problem is, share your experiences and guide me to know what is the right way to add another library files with **different** name from the MyThemeName?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You cannot.

Looking answer:
The purpose to for the libraries file is too define **all** the libraries of a **module** / **theme**.

The file is recognized because it is has the name of the theme/module it is placed at.

If you want libraries with a different namespace then you will need to search for an alter hook, and define these libraries there (not recommended).

Comment: @Eyal, what if you added that module as a dependency?

Comment: @YzmirRamirez what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you made a module a depency on another then you would guarantee that module existed and you could query the settings for it or the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the module docs, the theme docs are [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme). The advice is identical for both though:

> To define one or more (asset) libraries, add a *.libraries.yml file to your theme folder. (If your theme is named fluffiness, then the file name should be fluffiness.libraries.yml).

So if your theme is named MyThemeName, the libraries file should be named MyThemeName.libraries.yml, not libfile.libraries.yml

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, This Question linked to the module doc by mistake, let's move on, Here is my question how can I create a library with different name from MyThemeName?